# Get and Set value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function to show popup. So when the user clicks a link popup gets opened. Now what is the problem I have to set a value in the popup input type but I am not able to do that in javascript. I am doing this :

```
var email_id = document.getElementById("username_login").value;
```

From here i am getting value:

```
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:10px;">
        <input type="text" name="userName" id="username_login">
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Popup HTML**

```
<form  method="POST" name="ForgotPsswd">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7" width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>    
        <tr>
            <td width="26%" align="right">Email Address:</td>
            <td width="1%" style="padding:7px 5px;">:</td>
            <td width="74%"><input type="text" value="" size="33" class="border_grey" id="emailId" name="email"></td>
        </tr>          
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
 document.getElementById("emailId").value= email_id; //This is not setting the value
```

Comment: Please add the HTML also

Comment: alert the value of 'email_id' between these two lines.. Does that alerts the email?

Comment: i am getting value in email_id variable

Comment: document.getElementById("emailId").value= email_id; is the right way to do this, meaning that the issue might be coming from the value of email_id

Comment: When is execute the assignment ? I suspect is execute *before* the element exist.

Comment: are you firing a listener on form when emailId  is changing ?

Comment: Your code works in principal, but as others have stated, this is likely to do with how you're attaching your event. Here's a snippet of the code in action... https://jsfiddle.net/wtgw167t/

Comment: actauly the input in which i am trying to set the value is not on the it is coming from ajax so in the dom i am not getting that elment

Answer (score 0):

I have added a fiddle in which your code works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/uvjo86xa/

```
<form  method="POST" name="ForgotPsswd">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7" width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>    
        <tr>
            <td width="26%" align="right">Email Address:</td>
            <td width="1%" style="padding:7px 5px;">:</td>
            <td width="74%"><input type="text" value="" size="33" class="border_grey" id="emailId" name="email"></td>
        </tr>          
    </tbody>
</table>
    </form>

document.getElementById("emailId").value= "test@gmail.com"; //This is not setting the value
```

try setting the value after the html has rendered. i.e at the end and before the  tag. Also in your case, what is "email_id", for now try hard coding it and then check what the issue is.